# Should there be a comma between a noun and its adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, commas

Can "A white paper" be written as "A paper, white"?

Can "The nine planets" be written as "The planets, nine"?

Comment: What is the context? For a list of items 'a paper, white' could work well. I can see 'the planets, nine' working in some contexts as well.

Comment: It is not regarding a list of items.

Comment: As in can "Movement of the nine planets" be written as "Movement of the planets, nine"? and can "Words on white paper" be written as "Words on a paper, white"

Comment: There is no reason to invert the words like that unless you are listing items in alphabetical order of the noun. Why do you think you would want to?

Comment: So that a line rhymes with another in a poem. Are they grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Dashes are nice: [10—Dancing Girls—10](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/2010218519/1912-04-13/ed-1/seq-9/#words=%2210%2Bdancing%2Bgirls%2B10%22) (top left ad from 1912)

Comment: It would have been helpful to tell us that in your question! 'Poetic licence' allows for some unconventional usage.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) has: 'Phrases with postpositive adjectives are sometimes used with archaic effect, as in things forgotten, words unspoken, dreams believed. Phrases which reverse the normal word order are quite common in poetry, usually to fit the meter or rhyme, as with  ... "forest primeval" (from Evangeline), though word order was less important in Early Modern English and earlier forms of English.' 'In 1492,Columbus sailed the ocean blue ...' is a very well known example in poetry. // There are also modern ...

Comment: postpositive usages, different from the corresponding prenominal senses: 'Every star visible [tonight] has a name rather than just a number.' / 'The men responsible will be sought out.' // Some adjectives just must be placed after the noun ('poet laureate'). **But there is never a separating comma** (in standalone usages).

Comment: @Kate Bunting thank you so much

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Your reply has explained everything. Thank you so very much for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too difficult to find examples where your pattern appears. Here are three:

> [Tellus](https://medium.com/blueinsight/tellus-89-prologue-5a89e3ad9a07)
> *Around this circle planets, nine in number. A regularly rotating system, through billions of years.*

> [IMdB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6231588/)
> *Sinbad accidentally releases the Furies, three beautiful but terrible ancient beings*

> [google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YKnPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=%22man,+red+with+anger%22&source=bl&ots=PqAU16ehIT&sig=ACfU3U1ipcZi1EZqKrjXKAPehAzdULTE7Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimmO7OxJX3AhVjoFwKHQsEA9oQ6AF6BAgdEAM#v=onepage&q=%22man%2C%20red%20with%20anger%22&f=false)
> *replied the young man, red with anger*

We may also imagine constructs such as “A winter hare, white against a dark sky”.

However, in each case the pattern is part of a wider construction where the noun is followed by a descriptive adjectival phrase in apposition to the noun. This does not justify the idea that a noun may commonly be followed by a comma and a simple adjective.

Comment: The jury may be out over whether 'three' is class determiner subclass numeral, or class numeral. But I don't think _any_ grammarian would be happy to see it still classed as an adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I welcome your remark. As I wrote that part I realised my grammatical expertise is not adequate to deal with these terminological matters and I hoped for helpful comment.

Comment: The example is grammatical and has a similar though not identical structure. 'Sinbad accidentally releases the Furies, beautiful but terrible ancient beings' doesn't have the numeral twist.